# Image Super Resolution Algorithm with Wavelets in MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, matlab, discrete-signals, interpolation, superresolution

I'm trying to implement a simple Image super resolution algorithm (DWT-Based Resolution Enhancement
) in the following paper

[Discrete Wavelet Transform-Based Satellite Image Resolution Enhancement](http://www.ripublication.com/aeee/52_pp%20%20%20405-412.pdf)

I tried to implement the algorithm in figure 3 of this paper using Matlab.Code is given below.

```
img1 = imread('lena1.jpg'); %original High resolution image
[height, width, dim] = size(img1);

%%Downsampling the image by averaging
avgfilter = fspecial('average', [2 2]);
avgimg = filter2(avgfilter, img1);
img = avgimg(1:2:end,1:2:end); %Input low resolution image

[LL,LH,HL,HH] = dwt2(img,'haar'); %Decomposing

%Bicubic interpolation by factor 2 on each subbands
LL1 = imresize(LL,2,'bicubic');
LH1 = imresize(LH,2,'bicubic');
HL1 = imresize(HL,2,'bicubic');
HH1 = imresize(HH,2,'bicubic');

%% Calculating Difference image
for i=1:256
    for j=1:256
        img3(i,j,:) = img(i,j,:) - LL1(i,j,:);
    end
end


for i=1:256
    for j=1:256
        LH13(i,j,:) = img3(i,j,:) + LH1(i,j,:);
        HL13(i,j,:) = img3(i,j,:) + HL1(i,j,:);
        HH13(i,j,:) = img3(i,j,:) + HH1(i,j,:);
    end
 end

%bicubic interpolation(Here alpha = 2;Hence alpha/2 = 1) 
 img31 = imresize(img3,1,'bicubic');
 LH131 = imresize(LH13,1,'bicubic');
 HL131 = imresize(HL13,1,'bicubic');
 HH131 = imresize(HH13,1,'bicubic');

img4 = idwt2(img31,LH131,HL131,HH131,'haar'); %IDWT
t = uint8(img4)
imshow(t);
imsave;
```

Input image that I used is given below

[image]

But I'm getting a completely unexpected output as follows.

[image]
Why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code, looking at intermediate results and checking if they are sensible?

Comment: @Jazzmaniac Yes sir.I dont think that there is any mistake with the concept.May be due to some coding error.But couldn't find it out.

Comment: What you are displaying seems to be the gradient along both x and y

Comment: I am also suffering from same problem.. I think there is problem in difference of spatial domain and frequency domain signals..

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17186)

Comment: @user19982 : Please do not make a comment as an answer. Get more rep before commenting (you only need 50 or so to comment).

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not a good algorithm.
It is a native method to achieve upsampling.

I implemented the method:

```matlab
clear();
close('all');

wavType = 'haar';

intMethod = 'bicubic';

mImgRef = imread('https://i.imgur.com/8jvEQJX.png'); % Reference image
mImgRef = mImgRef(:, :, 1); %<! Working on a single channel
mImgRef = im2double(mImgRef);
[numRows, numCols] = size(mImgRef);

% Low resolution image
mImg = imresize(mImgRef, 0.5, intMethod, 'Antialiasing', true);

[mLL, mLH, mHL ,mHH] = dwt2(mImg, wavType); % Forward DWT

% Interpolation by 2 factor
mLL1 = imresize(mLL, 2, intMethod);   
mLH1 = imresize(mLH, 2, intMethod);
mHL1 = imresize(mHL, 2, intMethod);
mHH1 = imresize(mHH, 2, intMethod);

mDiffImg = mImg - mLL1;

mLH2 = mLH1 + mDiffImg;
mHL2 = mHL1 + mDiffImg;
mHH2 = mHH1 + mDiffImg;

% alpha = 2 -> No need for resize
mLL3 = imresize(mImg, 1, intMethod);
mLH3 = imresize(mLH2, 1, intMethod);
mHL3 = imresize(mHL2, 1, intMethod);
mHH3 = imresize(mHH2, 1, intMethod);

% High resolution image
mImgHr = idwt2(mLL3, mLH3, mHL3, mHH3, wavType);

% Display high resolution image
figure()
imshow([mImgRef, mImgHr]);
```

This is the output:

[image]